# using applescript to add my app to login item but getting a weird entitlement permission issue

Tags: swift, cocoa, applescript

I'm using this code to add my application in login items at app launch

```
         if tempVarForAddTologinItemAtLaunch == true{
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async{
            var error: NSDictionary?
            if let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: "tell application \"System Events\" \n if exists login item \"" + Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + "\" then \n delete login item \"myApp\" \n end if \n make new login item at end of login items with properties {name:\"" + Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + "\", path:\"" + String(Bundle.main.bundleURL.absoluteString).replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "").dropLast().replacingOccurrences(of: "%20", with: " ") + "\", hidden:false} \n end tell \n") {
                if let outputString = scriptObject.executeAndReturnError(&error).stringValue {print(outputString)} else if (error != nil) {print("error: ", error!)}
            }
        }
    }
```

I keep getting this error in the console
and the code doesn't work if I try my application in another user's account

2019-04-15 20:31:45.474846-0400 myApp[11185:13342142] skipped scripting addition "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/SASyphonInjector.osax" because it is not SIP-protected.

Comment: There is a bug in your AppleScript code, where your `exists NAME` tests uses the app’s bundle ID instead of its name. The safe ASOC-based implementation I posted below also fixes this bug. If your amended app continues to fail in another user’s account, update your question with a more detailed description of what it’s doing wrong to get further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding `SASyphonInjector.osax` error messages, as vadian says this is unrelated to your code.

vadian: “In 10.14 Mojave Apple doesn't allow third-party Scripting Additions anymore.”

This is not entirely correct. Third-party OSAX are still allowed, but they must be codesigned and embedded into the application that uses them (which must be signed with the same identity). However, OSAXen can no longer be installed in global “ScriptingAdditions” folders, nor can they be loaded into one process and then called from another (a massive code injection hole that Apple should’ve closed decades ago). There is a more [detailed writeup here](https://latenightsw.com/mojave-brings-in-big-security-changes/), c/o Late Night Software.

Unfortunately, Apple still allow StandardAdditions commands to be called remotely, so malicious code can still [e.g.] display fake “Please enter your Apple password:” dialogs in familiar apps such as iTunes and App Store. But assume OSAXen will eventually go away entirely.

The OSAX in question comes from [this project](https://github.com/zakk4223/SyphonInject), which used it to inject its own functionality into other apps. You can safely ignore the log error it now generates, though it won’t hurt to clean out your now-defunct “ScriptingAdditions” folders to silence it for good.

Comment: Why create a second answer just for an extended comment ?  Consider transplanting this to the end of your first answer as a footnote, or posting it as a series of comments against @vadian's answer.  Occupying an answer block is irksome and jarring to readers, but you potentially risk being downvoted, which could be annoying for you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not related to the code. In 10.14 Mojave Apple doesn't allow third-party Scripting Additions anymore.

You can simplify your code, replace

```
path:\"" + String(Bundle.main.bundleURL.absoluteString).replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "").dropLast().replacingOccurrences(of: "%20", with: " ") + "\", hidden:false}
```

with

```
path:\"" + Bundle.main.bundlePath + "\", hidden:false}
```

Comment: thx vadian, is there anyway to work around this or i should opt for a differant way to make the app launch at os launch?

Comment: You could use the native way to add the app as login item, for example have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030354/macos-swift-how-to-properly-add-application-as-login-item

Answer (score 0):

@vadian: **Never generate code from arbitrary strings.** Both OP’s code and your simplification of it are **fundamentally insecure** and should not be used.

The *correct* way to pass arbitrary arguments to `NSAppleScript` is to construct an `NSAppleEventDescriptor` holding the name of the handler to call and the data to pass to it, then call `-executeAppleEvent:error:` to invoke that handler.

That said, using `NSAppleScript` is [ridiculously tedious](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/nsapplescript.html), and it’s far easier to [call AppleScript handlers directly](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/asoc.html) via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge.

Here is some sample code for a `LoginItems.applescript`:

```
use framework "Foundation"

script LoginItems
  property parent: script "NSObject"

  to addLoginItem(appName, appPath)
    tell application "System Events"
      if exists login item appName then delete login item appName
      make new login item at end of login items ¬
          with properties {name:appName, path:appPath, hidden:false}
    end tell
  end addLoginItem
end script
```

It lacks niceties such as error reporting, but should get you started. And here is the corresponding Swift protocol:

```
@objc(NSObject) protocol LoginItems {
  func addLoginItem(_ appName: String, _ appPath: String)
}
```

You’ll need to add a few extra lines of boilerplate to your `AppDelegate` to load the script and instantiate the class (see the [Swift-AppleScriptObjC sample project](https://github.com/hhas/Swift-AppleScriptObjC) at the above link).

Oh, and also remember add an `NSAppleEventUsageDescription` string to your Info.plist, which is required for your App to send Apple events to other processes on 10.14+.